# IIS adds domain to website url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-5, iis-7

I have a ASP .NET MVC 5 project that is hosted with IIS7.

In a product page I have this code:

```
<a href="www.domain.com"> blabla </a>
```

It is hosted on domainx or ipx. Now when I browse to the site and hover over the url there, it shows me it is headed to www.domainx.com/www.domain.com. If I use the IP it is the same thing, but instead it prefixes the url with the IP.

What is causing this and/or how can I stop it/ prevent it from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had reproduced your issue in a sample project using SO as anchor hyperlink on index page (Views/Home/Index.cshtml), changing `http://` protocol to just www:

```
<a href="www.stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</a>
```

Surprisingly the URL generated on index page when hovering on the anchor link written as `[IP address]/www.stackoverflow.com` or `[domain name]/www.stackoverflow.com`.

However when `http://` protocol added without using www prefix, the absolute path rendered to correct SO URL.

I concluded that instead of only using www prefix, specify http protocol on your absolute URL path:

```
<a href="http://www.domain.com"> blabla </a>
```

or if you want to create your site root hyperlink use `Html.ActionLink` like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("blabla", "Index", "Home")
```

or use plain anchor tag:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">blabla</a>
```

IMHO, Razor view engine may treat URL string inside `href` attribute of anchor tag(s) as controller name under site root IP/domain if the URL protocol is not specified, thus HTTP prefix is required to differentiate between controller name and external absolute URL path.

Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. this did work, thank you :)